# Join 2 input Jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have code HTML basic

```
<div class="w-input-number-change">
    <input class="other-select input-number-change" type="radio" data-price="110" data-value="I will supply ___ pages of typed content" name="copy">
    I will supply 
    <input class="other-select input-number-change-value" type="number" data-price="110" data-value="pages of typed content" name="copy" value="1"> 
    pages of typed content. 
</div>
```

I get value input type radio

```
$content_radio =  $('.input-number-change').data('value');
```

I would choose input type radio, that show "I will supply **_ pages of typed content" with _** is value of input type number . How to get value from input numbers show when click input radio?

Comment: not sure what you are looking for

Comment: you view example https://www.designquote.net/html/dq_estimate_wizard.cfm
Topic "Copy"

Answer (score 1):

Remove `data-value` from input and you can easily get it as below:

**[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/f64fhxme/1/)**

**HTML**

```
<div class="w-input-number-change">
        <input class="other-select input-number-change" type="radio" data-price="110" name="copy"/>
         I will supply
        <input class="other-select input-number-change-value" type="number" data-price="110" data-value="pages of typed content" name="copy" value="1"/> 
        pages of typed content. 
</div>
```

**JS**

```
$('.input-number-change').on('click',function(){
    var value=$(this).siblings('.input-number-change-value').val();
    alert('I will supply '+value +' pages of typed content')
});
```

Comment: thank Guruprasad Rao, but if I have 1 input radio ( not include input number)  like to link https://www.designquote.net/html/dq_estimate_wizard.cfm, topic "Copy". So how get value ?

Comment: Not clear!! I saw in the link you provided and it is having same option which you've provided here!! Can you elaborate bit more pls!!